# media queries in css not working properly

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am using this code in my web page and I tried different settings for `min-width` but it take values only from the media query having least width.

```
@media only  screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    li{
        display: inline;
        padding-left : 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
    li.one{
        padding-left: 13%;
    }
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    li {
        display: inline;
        padding-left : 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;}
    li.two{
        padding-left: 9%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px),screen and (max-width: 601px) {
    li {
        display: inline;
        padding-left : 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
    li.three{
        padding-left: 7%;
    }
}
```

Don't know what is stopping other queries to work properly.

Comment: change this line to `@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 601px) {` also it will work only for width between 600px-601px

Comment: yes it should be but it is working for every width value

Comment: Lint your CSS, please.

Comment: here's the link-https://jsfiddle.net/qdgch6tm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) Your third query should be written like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 601px) {...
```

(a comma would mean two independent selectors)

2.) You made your `li` elements `inline` elements. But an inline element can't have any padding - all these padding values don't affect anything. So change the display settings to `inline-block` for these.

Answer (score 6):

Please add this code in your HTML page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: i was actually losing my mind, to try and figure out why none of my media queries would work, thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

`@media (min-width: 768px) {}` works for me. also add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to head tag

Answer (score 1):

The order of query sizes should be changed. In CSS, the last valid query wins, so the query falls though to the smallest. The largest should come last.

Answer (score -1):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    //your css class
}
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width:480px){
    //your css class
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width:720px) {
    //your css class
}

@media screen and(min-width: 721px) and (max-width:1080px) {
    //your css class
}

@media screen and(min-width: 1080px) and (max-width: 1280px){
    //your css class
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1281px) and (max-width: 1920px){
    //your css class
}
```

Try using your queries like this, this way worked for me

Comment: it is taking values from the min-width:320px only

Answer (score -1):

You have left one curly bracket inside 900 media query. Copy this code and replace media query.

```
@media only  screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    li {
        display: inline;
        padding-left : 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
    li.one{
        padding-left: 13%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    li {
        display: inline;
        padding-left : 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
    li.two{
        padding-left: 9%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 601px) {
    li {
        display: inline;
        padding-left : 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
    li.three{
        padding-left: 7%;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you want

Comment: padding between link boxes to be responsive and want to control the padding to make stuff little more interesting but all the control is given to the starting media query

Answer (score -2):

add this to in your head tag and close proper media query braces you didnt close do check properly.